# How to pass json data from API response to environment variable

Tags: javascript, api, environment-variables, postman

I am creating a record using POST method, then once I receive the JSON response, I want to take the "id" from this response and pass it into Postman's environment variable which I've set as "formId".

I have tried to use setEnvironmentVariable to set "formId" with record 1 from the json data specificially "id" data.

```
pm.test("Pass new form id to environment variable", function(){
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var formId =
    pm.setEnvironmentVariable("formId", jsonData[0].id);
})
```

This is the error I keep receiving:

Pass new form id to environment variable | TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

This is the json response:

```
{
    "created": "2019-08-12 05:45:35",
    "db": "1",
    "deleted": "0",
    "folder": "0",
    "id": "3548644",
    "language": "en",
    "name": "Test Form #3 - COPY 22",
    "num_columns": "1",
    "submissions": "0",
    "submissions_unread": "0",
    "updated": "2019-08-12 05:45:35",
    "viewkey": "coQv2xD54g",
    "views": "0",
    "submissions_today": 0,
    "data_url": "",
    "summary_url": "",
    "rss_url": "",
    "encrypted": false,
    "thumbnail_url": null,
    "submit_button_title": "Submit Form",
    "inactive": false,
    "timezone": "US/Eastern",
    "should_display_one_question_at_a_time": false,
    "can_access_1q_feature": true,
    "permissions": 150,
}
```

Comment: Can you check what `jsonData` looks like? Chances are it's not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: I've added the json response to the post for you guys to see.

Comment: if the json response is an object why the `jsonData[0]` ?

Comment: @Shubz — Why? The `0`th item of what list of items?

Comment: @Quentin What I have done there is wrong. I am struggling in referencing to 'id' in the response.

Comment: Tried this, but still get a similar error. Remove the [0] as it's not an array.


```pm.test("Pass new form id to environment variable", function(){
    var jsonData = postman.response.json();
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("formId", jsonData["id"]);
})```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no array in the JSON response that you shared.
When you write `jsonData[0]`, that means you're trying to access the value at 0th index of an array, but your jsonData is an object with 'id' property which can be directly accessed.

You just need to write this in the **Test** script (and not Pre-request script):

```
formId = jsonData.id;
pm.environment.set('formId', formId);
```

[image: Test script]

Comment: I have tried that but results in the following:

`Pass new form id to environment variable | TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined`

Comment: Your response never came through, that's why that happened.
Can you check the response? 

Also the API to set environment is `pm.environment.set` / `postman.setEnvironmentVariable` and not `pm.setEnvironmentVariable`

Comment: Wait, are you writing that script in `Pre-request script`? It should be written in the `Tests` section. Can you share the screenshot of the script and the response section?